# Programmatic ServerEndpoint wont work within Embedded Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

I have an embedded tomcat running and i am trying to setup websockets programmatically, can't use annotations, since i get the list of context paths dynamically. Using Java 8 and Tomcat 7.

Below is the code i am using,

Embedded Tomcat,

```
public class EmbeddedTomcat {
/**
 * @param args
 * @throws LifecycleException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws LifecycleException {
    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
    tomcat.setPort(5555);

    Context ctx = tomcat.addContext("", new File(".").getAbsolutePath());

    Tomcat.addServlet(ctx, "hello", new HttpServlet() {
        @Override
        protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            Writer w = resp.getWriter();
            w.write("Hello World !!");
            w.flush();
            w.close();
        }
    });

    ctx.addServletMapping("/hello", "hello");

    ctx.addApplicationListener(WSContextListener.class.getName());

    tomcat.start();
    tomcat.getServer().await();
}
```

}

WebSocket Listener to dynamically add the endpoints,

```
public class WSContextListener extends WsContextListener {

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    super.contextInitialized(sce);

    ServerContainer sc =
            (ServerContainer) sce.getServletContext().getAttribute(
                    Constants.SERVER_CONTAINER_SERVLET_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE);
    try {
        ServerEndpointConfig endPointConfig = ServerEndpointConfig.Builder
                .create(WSEndpoint.class, "/wshello")
                .build();
        sc.addEndpoint(endPointConfig);
    } catch(DeploymentException de) {
        de.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

The actual server endpoint class,

```
public class WSEndpoint extends Endpoint {

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see javax.websocket.Endpoint#onOpen(javax.websocket.Session, javax.websocket.EndpointConfig)
 */
@Override
public void onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig endpointConfig) {
    System.out.println(String.format("Opened a new session with Id[%s] associated to endpoint[%s]", session.getId(), session.getRequestURI().getPath()));

    session.addMessageHandler(new MessageHandler.Whole<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onMessage(String data) {
            System.out.println("Data received - " + data);
            session.getAsyncRemote().sendText(data);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) {
    System.out.println(String.format("Closing the connection to endpoint[%s] for session Id[%s] ", session.getRequestURI().getPath(), session.getId()));
    super.onClose(session, closeReason);
}

@Override
public void onError(Session session, Throwable throwable) {
    System.out.println(String.format("Error [%s] occurred on session Id[%s] associated to endpoint[%s]", throwable.getMessage(), session.getId(), session.getRequestURI().getPath()));
    super.onError(session, throwable);
}
```

}

Finally, the javascript bit to connect to the Websocket,

```
var webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5555/wshello");
```

I can access the servlet (http://localhost:5555/hello) and that bit works. The moment i try accessing the websocket via the above javascript code, it  fails with,

> websocket_test.html:18 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:5555/wshello' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5555/hello", "protocol");
```

The protocol added to handle websocket at the client side(optional).
Remove wshello "ws"

Comment: the javascript api is not an issue, since if i try hitting a public websocket server, it works. var webSocket = new WebSocket("wss://echo.websocket.org") The problem seems to be on the server end. Also the endpoint configured is "wshello" for websocket, so not sure why a servlet endpoint "hello" should be used there.